# JQuery not work with XML. Don't call WebMethod

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a page that created a table with XML data.
In my Code below, I coded a WebMethod that created XML data from SQL.
But, my page doesn't call this WebMethod and doesn't create this table.
Does this make sense?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        source =
        {
            datatype: "xml",
            datafields: [
                { name: 'User', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'RequestDate', type: 'DateTime' },
                { name: 'SituationDesc', type: 'string' }
            ],
            async: false,
            record: 'Table',
            url: 'Tickets.aspx/GetTickets',
        };
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
        });
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
            width: 670,
            source: dataAdapter,
            theme: 'classic',
            columns: [
              { text: 'Product Name', datafield: 'User', width: 250 },
              { text: 'Date', datafield: 'RequestDate', cellsalign: 'right', cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer, width: 100 },
              { text: 'Situation', datafield: 'SituationDesc', cellsalign: 'right', cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer, width: 100 },
            ]
        });
    });

<body class='default'>
<div id='jqxWidget' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;">
    <div id="jqxgrid">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public string GetTickets()
{
    string query = "SELECT [User],RequestDate,SituationDesc, FROM Ex";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    DataSet data = GetData(cmd);
    System.IO.StringWriter w = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    data.Tables[0].WriteXml(w, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema, false);
    return w.ToString();
}

private DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{

    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XX"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually declared a static method for your Ajax to call.

I haven't gone through all your code, though this part is for sure incorrect..

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public string GetTickets()
{
```

Should be **Note the 'static' declaration**

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
    public static string GetTickets()
    {
```

Also - try installing Firebug (or similar) - you will be able to see what errors are present from within the browser while trying to call the method. This will help you further identify any extra possible errors.

you will also need to declare `private DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)` as `static` after making the change above else it will not be accessible.

Comment: I changed to static, but still not work! Don't call WebMethod. I just have this code. It's all code!

Comment: then install firebug - it will give you ACTUAL error messages. Only then can we pin it down more...

Comment: Now is work! I was invoking cellsrenderer but was not declarig it. Now I need an help to align this table. I don't know work with design. How I can align and adapt size to each column, and the table in full size in my window?

Comment: You will have to ask a fresh question.